# Converting svn to git

Tags: git, svn

I've got a SVN repo I'm converting to git (I'm being dragged, kicking and screaming, into the 21st Century...!)

I'm following the instructions at https://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git, but realise they're pretty old, and I don't know how much git has changed recently.

The instruction in Section 5 is

```
git branch -m trunk master
```

but I only have `origin/trunk`, so running this command returns

```
$ git branch -m trunk master
error: refname refs/heads/trunk not found
fatal: Branch rename failed
```

Has git changed how it refers to the master branch since these instructions were written?

I'm also trying to work out if I actually need to do step 4? Can I push the result of Step 3 straight into a new github repo that I've created?

---

**more info**

In fact, all of my branches (apart from master) are prepended with `origin`:

```
svn2gitdir $ git branch -a
* master
  origin/add-pictures
  origin/fix-forms
```

From what I understand about git, this means it thinks they're remote?

If I set up a brand new local blank git repo, and add a branch, then they are truly local:

```
gittestdir$ git branch -a
  master
* mnb
```

I've used the following command to convert svn branches to git branches:

```
 for b in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/remotes); do git branch $b refs/remotes/$b && git branch -D -r $b; done
```

Is this a problem? What does it mean?

Comment: Just use SubGit instead of this mammoth's bullhiit

Comment: @LazyBadger I'm trying to understand git, and SubGit doesn't seem to explain what it's doing

Comment: I would recommend Bitbucket's comprehensive and up-to-date [Migrating to Git](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/svn-to-git-prepping-your-team-migration) instead.

Comment: For the person who voted this down, I'd appreciate some feedback on how you think I'd improve it.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you don't have a local branch named "trunk". 
if you execute the command `git branch --all`, you will see all local and remote branches. 
if you've pushed master already, you can checkout local branch under whatever name you wish with the command `git checkout -b local_branch_name remote_branch_name`

Comment: I think I've realised that `git svn` now makes the main branch name master by default, perhaps it didn't before - but I've also updated my question with some more info